# Angr installation failed in RPI3

Tags: pip, raspberry-pi3, angr

I am trying to install Angr tool on Raspberry pi 3, OS Ubuntu mate 16.04. Git link [Angr tool](https://github.com/angr/angr)

I isolated problem while installing pyvex getting this error, git link [Pyvex](https://github.com/angr/pyvex)

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running build
Building libVEX
cc -Ipub -Ipriv -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-qual -Wcast-align -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -Wformat -Wformat-security -std=gnu99 -fstrict-aliasing -fPIC  -g -malign-double -o auxprogs/genoffsets auxprogs/genoffsets.c
cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-malign-double’
Makefile-gcc:72: recipe for target 'pub/libvex_guest_offsets.h' failed
make: *** [pub/libvex_guest_offsets.h] Error 1
error: Unable to build libVEX.
```

`-malign-double` is for X86 architecture as per GCC documentation but i have arm architecture. How do I fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During build `PyVEX` downloads [`VEX`](https://github.com/angr/vex). I think you have to download it yourself, fix [Makefile](https://github.com/angr/vex/blob/master/Makefile-gcc#L46) and build. Then return to building `PyVEX`.

Report the problem to the [angr](https://github.com/angr/vex/issues) team.